# OrientDB how to match multiple related classes

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am trying to write a MATCH statement to pull related data.

```
CREATE CLASS Member EXTENDS V;
CREATE CLASS DirectVolumes EXTENDS V;
CREATE SEQUENCE dvSequence TYPE ORDERED;
CREATE CLASS GroupVolumes EXTENDS V;
CREATE SEQUENCE groupVolumesSequence TYPE ORDERED;
CREATE CLASS GenerationVolumes EXTENDS V;
CREATE SEQUENCE genGroupVolumesSequence TYPE ORDERED;
CREATE SEQUENCE memberIdSeq TYPE ORDERED;
CREATE VERTEX Member SET id=sequence('memberIdSeq').next();
CREATE VERTEX DirectVolumes set id=sequence('dvSequence').next(); 
CREATE VERTEX GroupVolumes set id=sequence('groupVolumesSequence').next();
CREATE VERTEX GenerationVolumes set id=sequence('genGroupVolumesSequence').next();
CREATE EDGE OWNS_DV_CURRENT FROM (SELECT FROM Member WHERE id = 1) TO (select from DirectVolumes where id = 1);
CREATE EDGE OWNS_PG_CURRENT FROM (SELECT FROM Member WHERE id = 1) TO (select from GroupVolumes where id = 1); 
CREATE EDGE OWNS_GG_CURRENT FROM (SELECT FROM Member WHERE id = 1) TO (select from GenerationVolumes where id = 1);
```

Now I want Member, andOWNS_DV_CURRENT, OWNS_PG_CURRENT, OWNS_GG_CURRENT edges data together. I have removed properties for simplicity.
What is the right way to do this with a MATCH? I didn't figure out how to fetch multiple related Classes. query seems ok but it returns 0 I think it is looking for OWNS_PG_CURRENT on top of OWNS_DV_CURRENT  and not on Member itself.

```
select from (MATCH {class: Member, as:member}.out("OWNS_DV_CURRENT"){as:dv}.out("OWNS_PG_CURRENT") {as: pg} RETURN member, dv,pg)
```

Comment: what about this without MATCH? `select @this as Member,out('OWNS_DV_CURRENT') as OWNS_DV_CURRENT,out('OWNS_PG_CURRENT') as OWNS_PG_CURRENT, out('OWNS_GG_CURRENT') as OWNS_GG_CURRENT from Member`

Comment: Thanks, looks like this works for me. Thank you. is this query a right way to get all properties of these nodes?      ` select Member.firstName as firstName,OWNS_DV_CURRENT.id, OWNS_PG_CURRENT.id,OWNS_GG_CURRENT.id from ( select @this as Member,out('OWNS_DV_CURRENT') as OWNS_DV_CURRENT,out('OWNS_PG_CURRENT') as OWNS_PG_CURRENT, out('OWNS_GG_CURRENT') as OWNS_GG_CURRENT from Member) `   how to I represent the target end of the edges and their properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 MATCH 
  {class: Member, as:member}.out("OWNS_DV_CURRENT"){as:dv},
  {as:member}.out("OWNS_PG_CURRENT") {as: pg} 
 RETURN member, dv,pg
```

Comment: Thank you, and I can read the properties within a select query on top of the match, is that correct understanding?     ` select member.firstName, dv.id, pg.id from (MATCH 
  {class: Member, as:member}.out("OWNS_DV_CURRENT"){as:dv},
  {as:member}.out("OWNS_PG_CURRENT") {as: pg} 
 RETURN member, dv,pg)`

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but you can also do it in the MATCH statement: MATCH ... RETURN member.firstName, dv.id, pg.id